# Having an issue to save through Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables Employee & EmployeeAddress joined by one to many relationship with Foreign key. When i am trying to save the Employee object i am getting the below log in my console. It might be this unidirectional joining is not happening properly.

```
2019-07-26 16:32:19 - SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2019-07-26 16:32:19 - Column 'EMP_ID' cannot be null
```

Below are POJO Classes: These are mapped with the DB tables.I am facing issues with the Join column.

Can any one please help me on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the POJO Classes and the mappings?

Comment: @Id
 @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
 private Integer id;
 
 @Size(min = 2, message = "Name should contain atleast 2 character.")
 @Column(name = "NAME")
 private String name;
 
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="employee",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private Set<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddress;
 
 public Employee() {

 }

Comment: Move the class into the Question,

Answer (score 1):

Try using:
`@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the issue is with Relationship so please make sure the following is correct

- `mappedBy` is used on the parent Entity and have the same name
  reference in Child Entity
- use `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST`, `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` or `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` (sometime) at Parent Entity
- `@JoinColumn` is used on Child Entity with correct reference column of Parent

*Parent.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int parentId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Child> child = new ArrayList<Child>();
}
```

*Child.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int childId;
    private String account;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Parent.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName = "parentId", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

*Controller*

```
@RestController
public class RelationshipController {

    @Autowired ParentRepository parentRepository;
    @Autowired ChildRepository childRepository;

    //save Child with Parent at same 
    @PostMapping(value = "/onetomany")
    public String OneToMany(@RequestBody Parent parent)
    {
        for (Child child : parent.getChild()) {
            child.setParent(parent);
        }

        parent.setChild(parent.getChild());
        parentRepository.save(parent);
        return "saved";

        /*{
            "name":"Romil",
            "child":[
               {"account":"1"},
               {"account":"2"}
             ]
        }*/
    }

        //save Child with Parent's ID
        @PostMapping(value = "/onetomanyPID")
        public String OneToMany(@RequestBody Child child)
        {
            child.setParent(child.getParent());;
            childRepository.save(child);
            return "saved";

            /*{
                 "account":"3",
                  "parent":{
                      "parentId":"1",
                       "name":"Romil"
                   }
            }*/
        }

}
```

Comment: No still i am getting an issue."Unable to find com.partha.spring.springBoot.employeeService.EmployeeAddress with id 2; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.partha.spring.springBoot.employeeService.EmployeeAddress with id 2",

Comment: Make sure you have a record with ID 2 in Table, please update the question with your relationship classes and other related code where you get the exception, Does it happens while saving an entity?

Comment: Hello @SerinPB, Please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful